# Firebase iOS Phone Authentication not working in Saudi Arabia

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I am not sure if this is location related, but our iOS app is not sending SMS authentication. We have implemented Firebase Phone Auth as documented and no SMS is being received.

our loginVC code:

```
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberWithCode, uiDelegate: nil) { [unowned self] verificationID, error in
          if let error = error {
              IndicatorManager.indicatorShared.stopIndecator()
              Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
              print(error.localizedDescription)
              print(error)
            return
          }
        IndicatorManager.indicatorShared.stopIndecator()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(phoneNumberWithCode, forKey: "userPhoneNumber")
        
        self.errorMessageLbl.text = ""
        let vc = SharedViewControllers().verificationCodeVC
        vc.phoneNumber = phoneNumberWithCode
        vc.phoneNumberWithoutCode = phoneNumber
        UserDefaultsConfig.phoneNumberWithoutCode =  phoneNumber
        var codeNum = codeNuber.text!
        if let pluse = codeNum.firstIndex(of: "+") {
            codeNum.remove(at: pluse)
        }
        UserDefaultsConfig.countryCode =  codeNum
        vc.countryCode = codeNuber.text!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
      }
}
```

Comment: According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#phone-auth-countries) phone authentication is supported for Saudi Arabia.

Comment: does it print any error?

Comment: no. There is no error, nothing..